# Clone action in hobo

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, controller, clone, customization, hobo

I am writing code to clone object but have no cue from Hobo documentation.

I know how to do it in Rails but it seems no intuitive way to do it in Hobo.

The scenario is to add an button on a record page, clone an existing record, and redirect to new record after the creation.

For example

```
POST /papers/10/clone
```

Then the new record 123 will be created.

After that action, it will redirect to page `/papers/123`

Are there any examples and guides to achieve the scenario?

If Paper has many Comments, how to clone them as well without permission errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hobo doesn't have any special support for cloning an object, so you'll have to drop down to Rails to do it:

```
def clone
  paper = Paper.find(params[:id])
  fail if paper.nil?
  clone = paper.clone
  clone.save!
  redirect_to paper_path(clone)
end
```

You could add this new controller action to your routes via Hobo's web_method hook, but that's designed for something else.   You're better off just adding it to your config/routes.rb in a standard Rails fashion.

Comment: how about has_many association?

I got an error when assigning duplicate objects in has_many association.

undefined method `with_acting_user' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyAssociation:0x007fdf4cf10c38>

Comment: Can you send me the full backtrace?   Perhaps the best place is to the hobo-users mailing list.   Thanks.